# How to extract the line between the pattern using sed

Tags: shell, sed

I have a file which has the below json data

```
    "comments": {
  "href": "https://api.github.com/repos/sumith08/myrepo/issues/xxxx/comments"
},
```

I am trying to extract a line from file using sed with below command.

```
sed -n '/"comments": {/,/}/p' commands.txt
```

The output should be only

```
https://api.github.com/repos/sumith08/myrepo/issues/xxxx/comments
```

But I get

```
        "comments": {
  "href": "https://api.github.com/repos/sumith08/myrepo/issues/xxxx/comments"
},
```

Can someone help me with the correct command please?

Comment: I suggest to use `jq`.

Comment: Do not parse json with shell tools, use `jq` instead. That said, the ugly hack of `sed -n '/"href":/s/^.*"\(https[^"]*\)"$/\1/p'` will work on your snippet. If you have another line formatted as `"href": "https....."` it will fail.

Comment: This question cannot be answered with any confidence that you will not receive unwanted results from other strings in your file. With a complete file, a complete answer can be provided. With only a limited snippet, no answer can guarantee a result. Please provide [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in several comments, `sed` might not be the right tool for the tast, whereas `jq` seems to be.

The following command works for the simple example you posted, but it's likely ineffective/wrong as soon as you use it on a slighly more complex JSON file.

```
sed -n 's/.*\(https.*\)"/\1/p'
```

Comment: Will also grab any other `https.*"` string in the file as well. But, it does extract the wanted URL from the snippet posted.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin obviously it does, but the example mentioned is very limited.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, thank you for the detailed explanation, I've tried to incorportate a "warning" in my answer.

Comment: Yep, that's the best you can do with the limited information provided. Always try and convey when there are factors outside what the questioner posted that may impact the solution (or request further clarification `:)`

Answer (score 0):

To exclude the start and end of the range, you can switch `p` to `{//!p}`

But that still leaves the entire line:

```
$ sed -n '/"comments": {/,/}/{//!p}' commands.txt
"href": "https://api.github.com/repos/sumith08/myrepo/issues/xxxx/comments"
```

So you can add on the other answer:

```
$ sed -n '/"comments": {/,/}/{//!s/.*\(http.*\)".*/\1/p}' commands.txt
https://api.github.com/repos/sumith08/myrepo/issues/xxxx/comments
```

`//!` is sed shorthand for lines not matching the previous match.